# Inverse property for groups Proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

I was wondering if (1) this proof is correct, and (2) if other proofs exist for the following:

Prove that $(a_1a_2...a_n)^{-1}=a_n^{-1}a_{n-1}^{-1}...a_1^{-1}$ where $a_i \in $ a Group $G$

Proof by induction

$(a_1)^{-1}=a_1^{-1}$

Let $n=k$.  Then $(a_1a_2...a_k)^{-1}=a_k^{-1}a_{k-1}^{-1}...a_1^{-1}$.  Then for $n=k+1$, we have

$(a_1a_2...a_ka_{k+1})^{-1}=[(a_1a_2...a_k)a_{k+1}]^{-1}=a_k^{-1}(a_1a_2...a_k)^{-1}=a_{k+1}^{-1}a_{k}^{-1}...a_1^{-1}$

This middle step occurs through the proof of $(ab)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}$ using group axioms to show that

$$(ab)(ab)^{-1}=e$$
$$a[b(ab)^{-1}]=e$$
$$b(ab)^{-1}=a^{-1}$$
$$(ab)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}$$

The above proof uses the fact that $(a_1a_2...a_n)\in G$.  Are there any other proofs that exist outside this induction proof or through the basic use of the group axioms?

Comment: In order to show that $(ab)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}$ just use associativity $$(ab)b^{-1}a^{-1}=a(bb^{-1})a^{-1}=aa^{-1}=e.$$

Comment: I meant to write outside group axioms and induction... are there any other proofs?